# How do I print non-Latin charcters in their original form?

Tags: java, arrays, unicode, char

I am trying create a program to print a random Arabic character.  The user then enters the Romanized wording, which the program validates.  The program repeats this process.

Instead of printing out the original character, my program it prints out **?**.  Can you identify the problem?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Arabic_Randomizer{
  public static void main(String[] args){

//the variables for 
//    char [] EngLetterEqv = {'a','b','g','d','h','w','z','h','t','y','k','l','m','n','s','','','','','','','','','',''};
    char [] achar = {'غ' , 'ظ' , 'ض' , 'ذ' , 'خ' , 'ث' , 'ت' , 'ش' , 'ر' , 'ق' , 'ص' , 'ف' , 'ع' , 'س' , 'ن' , 'م' , 'ل' , 'ك' , 'ي' , 'ط' , 'ح' , 'ز' , 'و' , 'ه' , 'د' , 'ج' , 'ب' , 'ا' };
    String [] ason = { "alif" , "baa" , "jim" , "dal" , "ha(2)", "wow" , "zai" , "ha(1)" , "ta" , "ya" , "kaf" , "lam" , "miim" , "noon" , "sin" , "'ayn" , "faa" , "sad" , "qaf" , "raa" , "scin" , "taa" , "tha" , "kai" , "dhal" , "Dad" , "za", "ghayn"};
    int randr = 0;
    int oi = 1;
    String ans = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// The "Game Loop"
    while (oi != 0){
      //Randomizer
      randr = (int) Math.random()*27;
      if (randr == 28){randr--;}
      //Selector & output
      System.out.println("What letter is this "+ achar[randr]);
      ans = scan.nextLine();
      //Check
      if (ans.equals(ason[randr])){System.out.println("Correnct");}
      else{System.out.println("Wrong");}
      //
      System.out.println("Please press 0 then enter if you would like to stop, press any other integer if you would like to continue; ");
      oi = scan.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

I am coding in DrJava; could that be the problem? I am new to Java and programming in general, so please use a simple response.

Comment: I'm not sure DrJava has very good support for extended character sets, if at all.  You might need to use a more capable tool like Eclipse, and set encodings for console and source to UTF-8.

Comment: Fixed grammar errors and flow of explanation.

Comment: I don't know what DrJava is, but if you can specify VM arguments, try `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user msandiford said, you need support for extended character sets. And as he said as well, Eclipse does the trick for that. Ran into kind of the same problem with Russian characters.

This will help you in the right direction:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Answer (score 0):

Just put `scan.nextLine();` below `oi=scan.nextInt();` and should be fine.